# View not displaying and centralising with autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I want to add a view in my view controller programmatically and centralise it. I added the view as subview to the parent view and enable autolayout yet its not showing.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var newView:UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.4745098054, green: 0.8392156959, blue: 0.9764705896, alpha: 1)
        view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
        return view
    }()


    let titleLable = UILabel()
    let bodyLabel = UILabel()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(newView)
        newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        newView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true



    }


}
```

Comment: You should be using either the frame based layout or autolayout. Not both. If you want to go with autolayout, you should proceed as suggested by Roman in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Size constraints are missing for `newView`. You removed them with `newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`. To restore all required constraints add the lines below to `viewDidLoad`:

```
newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView,
                   attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX,
                   relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
                   toItem: view,
                   attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerX,
                   multiplier: 1,
                   constant: 0).isActive = true

NSLayoutConstraint(item: newView,
                   attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY,
                   relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal,
                   toItem: view,
                   attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.centerY,
                   multiplier: 1,
                   constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the problem...
first, you set the frame of newView,
second, you also set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
so Xcode does not understand whats you want to set frame or constraints.
so if you set frame then you cannot add constraints again on it later.

so the best solution is here according to your need is:

```
view.addSubview(newView)
newView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

newView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
newView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
newView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
newView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
```

Comment: but how do I get the width and height of newView

Comment: @Darotudeen It's 200, or what do you mean?